# realm.objects().filter does not work with Resuts<T>

Tags: swift, realm

I tried to do query objects from Realm using `RealmSwift framefowk` with predicates:

```
realm.objects(Train).filter("ANY route IN %@", realm.objects(Route))
```

Error is:

> Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(String,
>   Results)'

The same code worked with `Realm framework` but does not work with `RealmSwift framework`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: is `.objects` an array?

Comment: My hunch is that the issue here is passing along the generic type when constructing the NSPredicate is a no-go for the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Results.filter(_:...)` takes arguments of type `(String, CVarArgType...)` but `Results` does not conform to `CVarArgType`. I've just created GitHub issue [#1995](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1995) to track this. The fix is pretty simple and I'd hope to have a PR up soon to address the issue.

In the meantime, you could convert `Results` and `List` arguments to `Results.filter(_:...)` to `Array` by using `map(_:_:)` like so:

```
realm.objects(Train).filter("ANY route IN %@", map(realm.objects(Route)) { $0 })
```

**EDIT:** PR [#1996](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/1996) making `Results` conform to `CVarArgType` is now pending review.

Answer (score 0):

Results aren't considerate as array in your case, you could make this simply with this piece of code. Have you tried to map `realm.objects(Route)` to return a array of identifier and filter on it with something like this : `ANY route.yourIdentifier IN %@` ?

Comment: realm.objects(Route) does not have method map. I don't know how to map Results from Realm (

Comment: You could create it, simply create an extension of Results with a function map which return an array of results count. This method take a closure as parameter and append the result of this closure for each result in your results.
This could be done because results are enumerable in RealmSwift ;)

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this extension

```
extension Results {
   func map<U>(transform: (T) -> U) -> Results<U> {
       return Results<U>(Swift.map(self, transform))
   }
}
```

but error is

```
'Results<U>' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

may be because Results cannot be created directly as to Realm docs.

Comment: That's correct, `Results` are not directly constructible outside of `RealmSwift` -- the framework provides the only ways of obtaining results.